# Dynamic hyperlink using formula

Tags: excel, formula

I need to use an ID in a URL hyperlink like this example:

> http://www.wotnots.co.uk/property/images/property2402_image1.jpg

The ID here is *2402*. I want to change it to the ID number which is in the first column and is different on every row. I want to have the ID number to be the same as the number in the hyperlink.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same comment and only just deleted it. The question is looking for an Excel formula to create a URL. There's not supposed to be content and it shouldn't really be a hyperlink.

Comment: ok - I see now. Tired brain = misread question.

Comment: Yeah well it took me about 5 reads and 2 tries to visit the link before I figured it out, so don't feel bad.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the HYPERLINK cell function to generate the link.  For example:

```
Cell A2: 2402
Cell B2: =HYPERLINK("http://www. ... /property" & A2 & "_image1.jpg","Click to see ...")
```

You can then copy the formula into all of the following rows, and the reference to cell A2 will change to be relative to the current row.

This can also be generated dynamically using VBA code if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

`=Concatenate("http://www.wotnots.co.uk/property/images/property",$A1,"_image1.jpg ")`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula:

```
="http://www.wotnots.co.uk/property/images/property"&A1&"_image1.jpg"
```